laravel filament personalizar inputs
Tengo un campo en la tabla 'testing' llamado 'parametros' que es una cadena de 8 caracteres asi "YNYYYYYY" cada caracter es un Si o un No, quiero verlas y editarlas y crearlas en forma independiente, osea 8 inputs y cuando salve, las concatene y las convierta en una sola cadena.
Con este codigo puedo ver cada caracter:
                Forms\Components\Toggle::make('S_1')
                ->label('S 1')
                ->default(function ($record) {
                    return $record ? substr($record->parametros, 0, 1) === 'Y' : true;
                }), 
            Forms\Components\Toggle::make('S_2')
            ->label('S 2')
                ->default(function ($record) {
                    return $record ? substr($record->parametros, 1, 1) === 'Y' : true;
                }),                                        
            Forms\Components\Toggle::make('S_3')
                ->label('S 3')
                ->default(function ($record) {
                    return $record ? substr($record->parametros, 2, 1) === 'Y' : true;
                }), 

y puedo cambiarlo pero no se como almacenarlo en la tabla todo junto en una sola cadena.
Muchas gracias

Estoy usando laravel 10 y filament 3, el codigo que tengo esta en el archivo 'TestingResource.php'
